# Update parent URL from an embedded GWT app?

Tags: gwt, gwt2

We are building a new app in GWT. This app will needed to be incorporated into an existing app. The server hosting the GWT app will be different than the server hosting the existing app. To get around the SOP issue, we plan to embed the GWT app in an iframe within the existing app. We would like to use history tokens to record page changes within the GWT app. This works fine, i.e. the back and forward buttons in the browser work as expected, EXCEPT that the URL of the parent page embedding the GWT app does not change to reflect the history token changes. Is there any way to modify the parent page URL from the GWT app embedded within an iframe? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found techniques to do so here: http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes. This is not specific to GWT but is doable in GWT. I tried the "Marathon" version and it works.